Supabase Auth callback asking for code_verifier and auth_code again after successful authentication
I'm encountering a really weird bug with Supabase authentication in my NextJS 13 app (using App Router) + FastAPI Python backend. Even after a successful sign-in/sign-up process, I'm getting an error about missing auth code and code verifier. Here's what's happening:
The Setup
I'm using Supabase for authentication, and I have an AuthCallback component that handles the OAuth callback:
// AuthCallback.tsx
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useToast } from "@/hooks/use-toast";
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { BACKEND_URL } from '../src/lib/utils';

export default function AuthCallback() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const { toast } = useToast();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleCallback = async () => {
      const code = searchParams.get('code');
      const provider = searchParams.get('provider');

      if (code) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/api/auth/callback/${provider}`, { code });
          if (response.data.user) {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.session.access_token);
            router.push('/dashboard');
          } else {
            throw new Error('Login failed');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Hack 
          if (error instanceof AxiosError && 
              error.response?.data.detail === "invalid request: both auth code and code verifier should be non-empty" && 
              localStorage.getItem('access_token') &&
              provider === 'google'
            ) {
            router.push('/dashboard');
          } else {
            router.push('/');
          }
        }
      } else {
        router.push('/');
      }
    };

    handleCallback();
  }, [searchParams, router, toast]);

  return <div>Processing authentication...</div>;
}

On the backend, I have a FastAPI route that handles the callback:
# auth.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, Depends
from supabase import create_client, Client
import os
from api.utils.auth_middleware import get_current_user
from pydantic import BaseModel

router = APIRouter()

url = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_URL")
key = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_SERVICE_KEY")
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)

class CallbackInput(BaseModel):
    code: str

@router.post("/api/auth/callback/{provider}")
async def auth_callback(provider: str, input: CallbackInput):
    try:
        response = supabase.auth.exchange_code_for_session({"auth_code": input.code})
        
        if response.user:
            return {"user": response.user, "session": response.session}
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Failed to exchange code for session")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in auth_callback: {str(e)}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))

The Problem
Using the debugger, I've confirmed that:

The code is successfully received from the URL parameters.
The backend successfully calls exchange_code_for_session and receives a valid response.
In the gotrue_client.py file, the exchange_code_for_session method is executed successfully:

# gotrue_client.py (excerpt)
def exchange_code_for_session(self, params: CodeExchangeParams):
    code_verifier = params.get("code_verifier") or self._storage.get_item(
        f"{self._storage_key}-code-verifier"
    )
    response = self._request(
        "POST",
        "token?grant_type=pkce",
        body={
            "auth_code": params.get("auth_code"),
            "code_verifier": code_verifier,
        },
        redirect_to=params.get("redirect_to"),
        xform=parse_auth_response,
    )
    self._storage.remove_item(f"{self._storage_key}-code-verifier")
    if response.session:
        self._save_session(response.session)
        self._notify_all_subscribers("SIGNED_IN", response.session)
    return response

I've verified that code_verifier exists in self._storage.get_item(f"{self._storage_key}-code-verifier") during this function call.

The access_token is successfully set in localStorage.

However, immediately after router.push('/dashboard') is called, I get the following error:
AxiosError: invalid request: both auth code and code verifier should be non-empty

This error is particularly puzzling because I can see that both auth_code and code_verifier are present and used successfully in the exchange_code_for_session method.
The Workaround
I've implemented a workaround that allows the authentication to succeed, but I'm not satisfied with it and want to understand why it's necessary:
catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof AxiosError && 
      error.response?.data.detail === "invalid request: both auth code and code verifier should be non-empty" && 
      localStorage.getItem('access_token') &&
      provider === 'google'
    ) {
    router.push('/dashboard');
  } else {
    router.push('/');
  }
}

This hack catches the specific error, checks if we have an access_token in localStorage (indicating a successful login), and if the provider is Google, it proceeds to redirect to the dashboard. While this workaround functions, it feels wrong and I'm concerned about potential security implications. I also get a console error saying the following error:

    POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/callback/google 400 (Bad Request)

What I've Tried

I've checked that code_verifier exists during the exchange_code_for_session call (it's inserted and deleted after the callback is finished).
I've confirmed that both auth_code and code_verifier are not empty when the exchange is happening.
I've stepped through the code line by line with a debugger (including to the implementation of exchange_code_for_session and can't see where this error is being thrown from.

Question
Why am I getting this error about missing auth_code and code_verifier when I can see that they exist and are being used successfully? It appears the error happens when it tries to run through the loop again, where the code_verifier is already destroyed.
I'm looking to understand the root cause of this issue rather than just relying on the workaround. Any insights into why this error is occurring, despite the successful authentication, would be greatly appreciated!
